# Remove number from list

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to remove the value 255 from my list, like if `a` or `b` or `c` or `d` equals to `255` I want to exclude it from the list.
I tried this `//list.removeAll (Collections.singletonList ("255"));` but it doesn't work .
When I compare the list's values with collection.max(list) I want to exclude 255 if one of values is equal to it.

```java
List<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();

list.add(a);
list.add(b);
list.add(c);
list.add(d);

if ( a>=15||b>=15||c>=15||d>=15) {
    if ( Collections.max(list) == a) {
        Defauts_detecteur.setText("Défauts récurrents constatés sur le détecteur 1");
    }else if (Collections.max(list)==b)
    {
        Defauts_detecteur.setText("Défauts récurrents constatés sur le détecteur 2");}
    else if (Collections.max(list)==c)
    {
        Defauts_detecteur.setText("Défauts récurrents constatés sur le détecteur 3");}
    else
    {
        Defauts_detecteur.setText("Défauts récurrents constatés sur le détecteur 4");}

    Conseil_detecteur.setText("--> Par mesure de sécurité, nous vous conseillons vivement de vérifier que le détecteur est bien collé au produit à sécuriser.\nPour une adhésion optimale, remplacez l’adhésif.\nVérifiez que le détecteur est bien connecté à la centrale et qu’il est en bon état.");

}
```

Comment: Did you try `list.remove(255f)` ?

Comment: `"255"` is a `String,` but your list is a List of `Float` so it will not contain any `String` that could be removed. Have you tried. `list.remove(255f)`?

Comment: No, I didn't try it

Answer (score 4):

The major problem (I'm guessing a little bit) is that you tried `.remove(255)` and it did not work.

That's because of an unfortunate quirk. This code seems extremely simple:

```
float a = 5;

List<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();
list.add(a);
list.remove(5.0);
// or even
list.remove(5);
```

The above code is **broken**. It compiles fine. It runs fine (well, the last one throws at runtime with a bizarre error message if you don't follow what is going on). And nevertheless, your list still contains `5.0` once it's ran. ??? What is going on here??

### What is going on?

There are 2 `list.remove` methods: One removes by value (you pass the value: The list will search all of the things it contains for that value and removes it), the other is by index: Remove the 9th value. They are different by way of argument type: The 'remove by value' one takes an Object, the 'remove by index' one an int. That's how java knows which one you want: What is the type of thing you pass to `remove`? Is it `int`, or `Object`?

When you write `.remove(5)`, you are removing by index. It gets complicated when you have a list of numbers, `.remove(5)` is ambiguous: Do you mean: Remove the 5th number, or do you mean: Remove the number 5?

This confusion explains why `.remove(5)` doesn't get the job done. Java always interprets that as: Remove by index. Even for a `List<Integer>`, it would do that.

Then, there's autoboxing. Java needs to convert your primitive to an Object in order to call the remove-by-value variant. `5.0` is converted to a Double. Which is also an object. It seems weird, but you can ask a list of Cats to remove a certain Dog: The list will just go: Oookay. And do nothing. It doesn't throw an exception, and it lets you write it. Contrast to add: You can't write `List<Cat> cats = ...; cats.add(new Dog())`. But you can write `cats.remove(new Dog())` just fine, under the theory that asking a list to remove something that isn't even in it, is fine, and is done by not doing anything.

That explains why `list.remove(5.0)` compiles, runs, and does nothing: It is asking to remove the **Double** with value 5.0, which your list doesn't have. It has a **Float** with value 5.0 and java does not treat those as the same.

You're doing `.remove("5")` which is even weirder: That is the string "5" which is utterly unrelated to the double or the float 5. Java does not try to conflate different concepts representing the same thing (`"5"`, `5F`, `5D` and  `5` are all different things).

### How to fix it

**Stop using float**. Use double instead. There is almost never a good reason for floats: The fact that they are smaller is rarely going to actually happen (64-bit architecture being what it is), and if it does, it is extremely rare you're in the tiny bandwidth where the savings of a float is worth it, but rewriting the code to use an algorithm that avoids floating point altogether is not. Double is a first class citizen in java, float is not. For example, `255.0` is a double. Not a float.

Next, dance around the fact that `.remove` is a bit daft. Cast to object to ensure it:

```
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(2, 1, 0);
list.remove(0); // this removes the 2!!! Because that is the item at index 0
list.remove((Object) 0); // this really does remove the 0.
System.out.println(list);
> [1]
```

Finally, ensure the things you try to remove match what is in your list. If you have a list of floats with 255 in it, that'd be `255F`. Not `255`, not `255.0` (which is a double). `255D` and `255.0` are the same, though:

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
list.add(255.0);
list.remove(255.0); // this works
list.remove(255); // this doesn't
list.remove((Object) 255); // this removes nothing! 255 isn't the same as 255.0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Created ArrayList is type of Float. So the below snippet will delete all the occurences of 255f

```
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(255f));
```

Below is the code snippet I tried by myself

```
List<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();  
list.add(1.0f);  
list.add(2.0f);  
list.add(255.0f);  
list.add(3f);  
list.add(255f);  
System.out.println(list.toString());  
//output [1.0, 2.0, 255.0, 3.0, 255.0]
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(255f));  
System.out.println(list.toString());  
//output [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```